# Set the time range

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I would be grateful for your help. How to set the range from 15 December to 15 January?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
if (month < 2 || month === 11) {
    $("#block").css("background-color", "#1D30C4");
}
else {
    $("#block").css("background-color", "#C41D2C");
}
```

});

Comment: Please don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var block=$('#block');

var cd= new Date();
var startDate= new Date(cd.getFullYear(),11,15,0,0,0,0);
var endDate= new Date(cd.getFullYear()+1,0,15,0,0,0,0);

if(cd.getTime()>=startDate.getTime() && cd.getTime()<=endDate.getTime()){
  $("#block").css("background-color", "#1D30C4"); 
}else{
  $("#block").css("background-color", "#C41D2C");
}
```

please note that month in javascript starts with 0
here is jsbin link
https://jsbin.com/tafijucono/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth();
if((month > 11 && day > 14) || (month < 2 && day < 16)){ ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works like this:
if((month > 1 && day > 14) || (month < 2 && day < 16)){

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be compared as if they are integers (since they contain a [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range) that is an integer representing an instant in time). So if you want to see if a date is between two other dates, then you can create two date objects and see if others lie between them:

```js
// See if currently between 15 December 2015 and 15 January 2016 inclusive

// Start at 15-Dec-2015 00:00:00
var startDate = new Date(2015,11,15);

// End at 16-Jan-2015 00:00:00 so includes 15 Jan but not 16 Jan
var endDate = new Date(2016,0,16);
var now = new Date();

if (now > startDate && now < endDate) {
  document.write("In range");
} else {
  document.write("Out of range");
}
```